# xlsx-js parse from stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js, xlsx

I'm trying to parse a file using xlsx-js (v0.8.0) which is piped via stdin.

The following code:

```
const data = fs.readFileSync('/dev/stdin').toString();
wb = xlsx.read(data, {type: 'binary'});
```

fails when I pipe the file (on a mac) as cat foo.xlsx | node test.js:

```

> throw new Error("Corrupted zip : can't find end of central directo
>                     ^ Error: Corrupted zip : can't find end of central directory   at Object.ZipEntries.readEndOfCentral
>   (/Volumes/Macintosh_HD/Users/shauncutts/src/crane-parse-monthly/node_modules/jszip/lib/zipEntries.js:135:19)
>   at Object.ZipEntries.load
>   (/Volumes/Macintosh_HD/Users/shauncutts/src/crane-parse-monthly/node_modules/jszip/lib/zipEntries.js:197:14)
>   at Object.ZipEntries
>   (/Volumes/Macintosh_HD/Users/shauncutts/src/crane-parse-monthly/node_modules/jszip/lib/zipEntries.js:21:14)
>   at Object.module.exports [as load]
>   (/Volumes/Macintosh_HD/Users/shauncutts/src/crane-parse-monthly/node_modules/jszip/lib/load.js:11:18)
>   at Object.JSZip
>   (/Volumes/Macintosh_HD/Users/shauncutts/src/crane-parse-monthly/node_modules/jszip/lib/index.js:39:14)
>   at read_zip
>   (/Volumes/Macintosh_HD/Users/shauncutts/src/crane-parse-monthly/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:11375:38)
>   at Object.readSync [as read]
>   (/Volumes/Macintosh_HD/Users/shauncutts/src/crane-parse-monthly/node_modules/xlsx/xlsx.js:11396:11)

However, I can read the same file via:

```
wb = xlsx.readFile(fn);
```

Without a problem. How should I modify my code to be able to read a piped file?

Comment: Have you tried to set binary encoding: `fs.readFileSync('/dev/stdin').toString('binary');` ?

Comment: @LazarevAlexandr --sounds promising, but neither `toString('binary')` nor `toString('ascii')` worked....

Comment: Seems to be problem with `fs.readFileSync('/dev/stdin')`: string is 65536 length vs 1746435 when read as file. -- perhaps this is getting stuck at an EOF character somewhere in the middle of the binary data? Or is 65536 size of an internal buffer? Hmm... any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, most probably the problem is with getting a binary string from the file. Try to set `binary` encoding as an option param of  `readFileSync` and do not call `toString()` after it. As it is described here: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_file_options

Answer (score 1):

Thanks again to @LazarevAlexandr ... in fact the problem is that [readFile & readFileSync have problems with stdin](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/52950e1e53c19a56fad3). The following code works:

```
  let wb;
  const chunks = [];
  process.stdin
    .on("data", function(chunk) { chunks.push(chunk); })
    .on("end", function() { 
      const buffer = Buffer.concat(chunks);
      wb = xlsx.read(buffer, {binary: true});

      // (call your favorite async continuation method here...)
    });
```

(NB -- tried passing binary option to readFileSync in @mbostock's tests and they still stopped at 65535).